# Does using a lambda slot function in a signal cause a memory leak

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I used the lambda slot function in the signal. The lambda passed an additional parameter patient, patient is a QWidget object. Will this cause a memory leak? The reason I asked this question was a sentence I saw in this article: Don't use lambda function as a slot. It is impossible to disconnect it. The article address: http://enki-editor.org /2014/08/23/Pyqt_mem_mgmt.html, I understand it this way. The lambda function that cannot be disconnected causes the patient object to never be released and causes a memory leak.

```
patient.close_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.delete(patient))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you link to is very old and appears to refer to Qt4.  Using Qt5/PyQt5 you can store the connection instance...

```
conn = patient.close_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.delete(patient))
```

and use it later to disconnect from the signal...

```
patient.close_btn.clicked.disconnect(conn)
```

**Edit 1:**
Had another look at this and it appears, with PyQt5 at least, that you can disconnect a lambda *without* storing the returned connection instance provided you store the lambda itself as a variable.  So connect with...

```
l = lambda: self.delete(patient)
patient.close_btn.clicked.connect(l)
```

and disconnect with...

```
patient.close_btn.clicked.disconnect(l)
```

But the following doesn't work...

```
patient.close_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.delete(patient))
patient.close_btn.clicked.disconnect(lambda: self.delete(patient))
```

Since the two lambdas, although functionally identical, actually refer to different variables.  Note that this is with Qt5/PyQt5.  Not sure if the same holds for Qt4/PyQt.

Comment: Prior to Qt5 the various `QObject::connect` overloads only returned a `bool` to signify success or failure.  There was no way to refer to a specific connection.

Comment: I wonder where the best place for this kind of clean up code would be. Do we need to do that in our `closeEvent` implementation for example? What if the same instance of the widget is shown again? In c++, such cleanup code usually belongs in the destructor. In pyQt, it seems that we need to use something else?